# The app does not resize its component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have this app, but, when I resize the window, the element `JTextArea` inside, it doesn't resize with the window. Why?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleGUI {

private JTextArea text_area;
private JScrollPane scroll_bar;

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;

public ExampleGUI(){

    frame = new JFrame("Example GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    text_area = new JTextArea();
    scroll_bar = new JScrollPane(text_area);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scroll_bar);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new ExampleGUI();}});
}
}
```

Comment: Why not simple comment this line frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); Regards

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @GagandeepBali - The default layout for a JPanel is a FlowLayout, so that line doesn't actually do anything useful. Commenting it out won't change the behavior.

Comment: @TedHopp : it's frame's layout he is setting, not the panels. Frame's default is BorderLayout. Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali - You're right. I don't know why I was thinking it was a JPanel.

Comment: @TedHopp : :-) It's okay, no worries.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your GridBagConstraint x and y weights (weightx and weighty -- the 5th and 6th parameters in the GridBagConstraint constructor) to a positive value other than 0.0. You should read tutorials on GridBagLayout if you're going to use it as it is fairly complex. Some have had great success nesting simpler layouts or using 3rd party layouts such as [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to nest simpler layouts. You can do a lot with just `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout`, `BoxLayout` and the `Box` component, without the headache of `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Your frame layout is a FlowLayout. This does not resize children. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html):

> A flow layout lets each component assume its natural (preferred) size.

You will be better off using a BorderLayout and putting the pane in the CENTER.

Replace this:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.add(pane);
```

with this:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, as Hovercraft points out, if you need the individual components to resize when the pane resizes, then you need to have non-zero weights in the GridBagConstraints.

Comment: Didn't see that, 1+. Sounds like the OP needs to read the whole layout manager tutorial.

Comment: But the text area remain of the same dimension.

Comment: @Mazzy: of course the text area remains unchanged -- you've set the preferred size of the enclosing JScrollPane.

Answer (score 3):

This takes into account the advice of Hovercraft Full Of Eels & Ted Hopp with a few other tweaks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Collection;

public class AziendaGUI implements ActionListener {

private JButton view_list;
private JButton save_list;
private JTextArea text_area;
private JScrollPane scrollpane;
private JPanel pane;

private JFrame frame;
private GridBagLayout grid;

public AziendaGUI() {

    frame = new JFrame("Immobiliari s.p.a");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    view_list = new JButton("View Property");
    view_list.setActionCommand("view_list");
    view_list.addActionListener(this);

    save_list = new JButton("Save List");
    save_list.setActionCommand("save_list");
    save_list.addActionListener(this);

    text_area = new JTextArea(10,22);
    text_area.setEditable(false);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(text_area);

    grid = new GridBagLayout();
    pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(grid);

    /* Set Constraints view_list button */
    grid.setConstraints(view_list, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,0.0,0.0,GridBagConstraints.WEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0));
    pane.add(view_list);

    /* Set Constraints save_list button */
    grid.setConstraints(save_list,new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1,0.1,0.1,GridBagConstraints.EAST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0));
    pane.add(save_list);

    frame.add(scrollpane);

    frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void store(){

    String file_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserisci il nome del file");

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    String s = e.getActionCommand();

    if(s.equals("view_list")){
    }
    if(s.equals("save_list")){

        store();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){@Override
                                              public void run(){new AziendaGUI();}});
}
}
```

Comment: Why add the pane as the NORTH component? It would make more sense to add the pane as the CENTER component so it would expand vertically as well as horizontally.

Comment: @TedHopp Look more closely at the code.  Tests show the extra vertical space assigned to the text area.